# Line break after printing array?

Tags: php, arrays, line-breaks

Alright I'm saving contents from a web crawler into a textfile, but problem is the crawler goes through multiple urls, so I use a foreach loop on the urls array..

But when I'm printing my data into file, each array pulls 49 entries, and every 49th line theres a double entry.

Is there anyway I can line break after printing each array from foreach loop?

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $source = file_get_contents($url);
    $roughHtml = rough_html($source);
    $scraped = extract_ips($roughHtml);
    $readyD = implode("\n", $scraped);
    file_put_contents($filename, $readyD, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

It's printing the array fine; and the data is in the file; but every 49th line is:

```
124.232.136.12:2160
196.201.216.170:779186.89.105.127:8080
186.95.69.6:8080
```

Any help with this issue?

Comment: `$readyD = implode("\n", $scraped) . "\n";` maybe?

Comment: are you sure it's a double entry? I'm guessing your input file simply doesn't end with a line break, so the first entry of the next file simply shows up glued to the end of the last entry of the previous file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a new line to `$readyD` in `file_put_contents`.

```
file_put_contents($filename, $readyD . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
                                       ^^
```